# How can I recursively find files and then execute code

Tags: python, glob

So I was trying to make it to where this script will run through each folder individually and then execute data decompression code. Please Refer to my code in below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
import zlib
import sys
import glob



if file in glob.iglob('**/*.data', recursive=True):

    data_file = sys.argv[1]

    data = open(data_file, "rb").read()
    deco = zlib.decompress(data)

    wrfd = open(data_file + ".dec", "w")

    wrfd.write(deco.decode("utf8"))
    wrfd.close()
    print("Data {} decompressed to {}".format(data_file, data_file + ".dec"))
```

What Am I doing wrong because when I execute it, it shows nothing as like it completed; yet nothing was decompressed from the .DATA Files.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues in your code

1. Instead of "if" condition, you should use for loop to iterate through all the files
2. You should use "file" parameter to read from the file, instead of what you receive from command line.

If my answer didn't solve your issue, please post complete code.